# bash: combine all elements of two arrays (and add something to each)

Tags: arrays, string, bash, expansion

I have two bash arrays and want to combine all elements of both, plus add a string to each resulting element.

Specifically, I have an array containing some years and another with some months, and want the date string of the first day of each month in each year:

```
# Define arrays containing some years and months (zero-padded)
yyyys=(2000 2001 2002)
mms=(12 01 02)

# I want to achieve the following using the arrays defined above
echo {2000..2002}{12,01,02}01 # 20001201 20000101 20000201 20011201 ...

# For hard-coded months, the following does what I want
echo ${yyyys[@]/%/0101} # 20000101 20010101 20020101

# How can i achieve this for arbitrary months, using $mms?
```

How can I achieve this with as little code as possible?

Note: I need this for a (dirty enough) bash run script, so I'm not looking for a clean, portable solution but a condensed bash solution using string expansion, piping, or whatever else necessary. (I could write a function to achieve this in a few lines of code without any problem, so that's not the point).

Answer (score 0):

I've found a partial solution based on brace expansion:

```
eval echo $(echo "{${yyyys[@]}}{${mms[@]}}01" | sed 's/ /,/g')
# 20001201 20000101 20000201 20011201 20010101 20010201 20021201 20020101 20020201
```

However, this only works if both arrays contain more than one element, otherwise the braces are not resolved.

Given one-element arrays are a very real use case, I've nevertheless written a function:

```
# Create timesteps from combinations of years, days, months, hours
# - $1 year(s), e.g., 2001, 2004-2006+2008
# - $2 month(s), e.g., 06, 12+01-02
# - $3 day(s), e.g., 01, 01-28
# - $4 hour(s), e.g., 00, 00+06+12+18
create_timesteps()
{
    local ys=($(expand_list_range ${1}))
    local ms=($(expand_list_range ${2}))
    local ds=($(expand_list_range ${3}))
    local hs=($(expand_list_range ${4}))

    local expr=""
    [ ${#ys[@]} -eq 1 ] && expr+="${ys}" || expr+="{${ys[@]}}"
    [ ${#ms[@]} -eq 1 ] && expr+="${ms}" || expr+="{${ms[@]}}"
    [ ${#ds[@]} -eq 1 ] && expr+="${ds}" || expr+="{${ds[@]}}"
    [ ${#hs[@]} -eq 1 ] && expr+="${hs}" || expr+="{${hs[@]}}"

    expr="$(echo "${expr}" | sed 's/ /,/g')"
    eval echo "${expr}"
}
```

I'll refrain from accepting my answer for now, though, in hopes of a different answer more along the lines of my original question.